# How to find the number of the day in a year based on the actual dates using Pandas?

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas

My data frame `data` has a date variable `dateOpen` with the following format `date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"` and I would like to have a new column called `openDay` which is the day number based on 365 days a year. I tried applying the following

```
data['dateOpen'] = [datetime.strptime(dt, date_format) for dt in data['dateOpen']]
data['openDay'] = [dt.day for dt in data['dateOpen']]
```

however, I get the day in the month. For example if the date was `2013-02-21 10:12:14.3` then the above formula would return 21. However, I want it to return 52 which is 31 days from January plus the 21 days from February.

Is there a simple way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On *latest* pandas you can use [date-time properties](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties):

```
>>> ts = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(['2013-02-21 10:12:14.3']))
>>> ts
0   2013-02-21 10:12:14.300000
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> ts.dt.dayofyear
0    52
dtype: int64
```

On older versions, you *may* be able to convert to a `DatetimeIndex` and then use `.dayofyear` property:

```
>>> pd.Index(ts).dayofyear  # may work
array([52], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Nice - hadn't noticed that in 0.15.x's release notes :)

Comment: @behzad.nouri Just updated to the latest version of Pandas and your first solution worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there's a `pandas` builtin, but in Python, you can get the "Julian" day, eg:

```
data['openDay'] = [int(format(dt, '%j')) for dt in data['dateOpen']]
```

Example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> int(format(datetime(2013,2,21), '%j'))
52
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#To find number of days in this year sofar

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
print("Today's date:", today)
print(int(format(today, '%j')))
```

Today's date: 2020-03-26
86